# SQL Loader- data not uploaded to the table. All went to .bad

Tags: sql-loader

I tried to upload some records into my table `ABC`. None of the records went through and they all showed up in the `.bad` log.

I am pretty new to sqlldr. Not quite sure where did I messed up. Let me show you the steps I took.

First, I created an empty table called `ABC`.

```
 create table abc
    (
      location_id varchar2(10),
      sold_month date,
      item_name varchar2(30),
      company_id varchar2(10),
      qty_sold number(10),
      total_revenue number(14,3),
      promotional_code varchar2(10)
    );
```

Here is my flat file `abcflat.dat`. The columns correspond to the columns in the table above.

```
"1000","02/01/1957","Washing Machine","200011","10","10000","ABCDE"
"1000","05/02/2013","Computer","200012","5","5000","ABCDE"
"1000","05/01/2013","Bolt","200010","100","500","ABCDE"
"1000","05/03/2013","Coca Cola","200011","1000","1000","ABCDE"
```

Here is my control file `abc.ctl`

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Users\Public\abcflat.dat'
INTO TABLE ABC
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
enclosed by '"'
(
Location_ID
, Sold_month
, item_name
, Company_id
, QTY_Sold
, Total_revenue
, Promotional_Code
)
```

And my last step

```
sqlldr hr/open@xe control=c:\users\public\abc.ctl
```

It says

```
Commit point reached - logical record count 3
Commit point reached - logical record count 4
```

but none of the record showed up on my ABC table.

Thank You

Comment: Rows going into the bad file means that the format is different than what is expected by the loader....  The problem is with the DATE column. You have to provide a to_date function with the proper format string... To verify this, you could create a similar table, with a varchar2 column instead of the date, and try your sql loader script

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the .bad file only replicates the records that didn't go through. It didn't specify any reasons. A .bad file was create automatically but a log wasn't. Do I have to create a log manually when I enter the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably the date format, try this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Users\Public\abcflat.dat'
INTO TABLE ABC
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
enclosed by '"'
(
Location_ID
, Sold_month DATE "DD/MM/YYYY"
, item_name
, Company_id
, QTY_Sold
, Total_revenue
, Promotional_Code
)
```

Comment: Yes it works. I thought I tried that but it didn't work out before. Anyway I have a quick question: if my flat file's data contains quotations, then I have to use enclosed by '"' ?

Comment: @GoodLooking: yes you need `enclosed by '"'`